# Azure Pipelines: Usage of two templates after each other fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm having difficulty with setting up my Azure multi stage pipeline. I tried to run two templates after each other in every environment. However, this is failing due to the following message:

> Unexpected value 'steps'

The code I'm using is:

```
  - ${{ each environment in parameters['environments'] }}:
    - template: pipeline_templates/deploy_environment_dp.yml # All jobs and steps required in order to deploy the aplication are defined in this template. Further details on steps in this template will be explained in the template itself.
      parameters:
        environment: ${{ environment }}
    - template: security/owaspzap.yml@templates
      parameters:
        appUrl: '##'
        owaspZapRunmode: 'baseline'
```

My feeling says it is not possible to run a step template after a stage template, but I can't find anything about this and also I don't know the solution for this.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your feeling is correct. When you include a `template` reference, the contents of the template is inserted into the YAML document at the location specified. If that creates an invalid YAML document, you'll get errors. In this case, you're trying to insert a list of `step`s in a scope where they are unsupported. You'll have to move the steps to a supported scope.

There are numerous ways to address the issue, but the best choice is going to be up to you to determine based on your requirements.

Some examples of possible resolutions:

- Make your first template take an optional `stepList` parameter and pass the `step` template in
- Make your second template into a separate stage
- Combine the two templates together

And so on.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying! There is some extra difficulty as the second template is created outside our department, so changing that will cost a lot of discussions. 

Secondly, in the first template I tried to add another template but the resource property wasn't allowed.

I also tried to create a separated stage for the second template, but this didn't work out. How would you set this up?

Comment: Without seeing the full templates, I can't provide any further guidance. A `stepList` parameter (i.e. my first suggestion) would probably work out. Refer to the documentation for more information on how to use `stepList` parameters.

Comment: It’s best not to think of templates as something that get executed — they’re expanded into a single file. The file must comply with the pipeline yaml schema.